# Dynamic DB ConnectionString configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, multi-tenant, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We created a web application using ASP.NET 4 and WEB API (separate API services)
Client application will call the api and connect to the DB from API.
We wanted to host the app services enabled in azure (Single instance with different CNAME Mapping)
I got a question on DB connection for various hosts from the API. What is the best way to establish the connection string based on the host name being passed from the client web application?. Currently, we used to get the connectionstring dynamically from DB based on the tenant in every call But that is hitting the performance.
Sample Code

`using (var hostdbConnection = new SqlConnection(GetTenantDBCon(string hostname)))
                {
                    hostdbConnection.Open();........}`

there were some examples to set the host connstring in DBContext (We dont use entity framework)

I hope to use the AzureSettings to save all the host connection strings instead of Database and connect them using configurationManager. I hope it will be secured too.

```
var hostdbConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[“HOSTNAME_ConnString”]
```

Any suggestions and best solutions?

Thank you !!!

Comment: It really depends on the amount of various connection strings you have and how often they might change. If the amount is relatively low than you can stuff all of them into the configuration file. If it's high and can change - store it externally (DB, API service) and get it but not on every call, cache them instead. Use an existing caching implementation or simply create a static key-value dictionary, configure the timeout value and on first hit load it and store in the cache. When the timeout expires - request again.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your reply. the tenants count is going to be large. Also, We are establishing DB connection in a WEBAPI AppService because it can be consumed by all the client type (website and mobile app). I am not sure if we can enable cache in the webapi service. I hope that is not advisable because the service needs to be stateless..

Comment: You most certainly can, I can't see anything that prevents it. Cache does not constitute state. It just holds whatever is in the database and makes it accessible without making a DB call.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. If possible, please provide any sample that uses redis cache in the rest api which needs to be hosted in the azure as appservice

Comment: This link has a pretty good description of how to work with Redis cache: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache#add-object. However, please note that Redis cache call is still a call and it's not in-memory. If you still experience slowness you might want to create a static Dictionary class which holds the key-value pairs + time it was populated. The `GetDbConnectionString` method than would check the time and if it's within the expiration limit - return from the Dictionary. Otherwise - call Redis/DB, update the cache and return new record